# Stop touch screen press from moving mouse pointer Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchscreen

I have a 2 screen setup with Windows 8 pro, one is a normal monitor and the other is a touch screen. When using the touch screen to do anything it moves the mouse pointer to that location and then I have to move it back across when switching to my main monitor.

It doesn't make much sense for the touch screen to move the pointer as it is irrelevant to the way you interact with the screen. I looked through the touch settings and couldn't find anything, is there any way from within Windows to stop this?

[This related question](https://superuser.com/questions/565025/stopping-the-mouse-cursor-from-moving-when-using-a-touchscreen-and-multiple-moni) one refers to Windows 7, Windows 8

Comment: @Sathya I thought only questions with an accepted or upvoted answer can be used as "duplicate target" ? Am I wrong?

Comment: @nixda you're right, but this was asked & closed long, long ago

Comment: is it connected via USB?

Answer (score 4):

Use AutoHotkey to track the previous position of mouse. Once the touch event occurs, reset the location of the mouse.

Comment: Can you provide example code?

Comment: Sorry, no time, but please share it if you find it out.

Answer (score -1):

That is the design of touchscreens.  When you touch a touchscreen, your finger becomes the mouse.  If the mouse controls the cursor, and your finger is the mouse, then your finger controls the cursor.

Comment: I realize that is the way it works, I am looking for a way to change the functionality

Comment: @user1816968 Can't be done.

Comment: @Kruug I'm thinking a program could pretty easily be setup to change this functionality... The issue with this would be that it could appear to be a "mouselogger(? mouse version of a keylogger)" where the app tracks the previous position of mouse. Once the touch event occurs, it would reset the location of the mouse. Just a thought.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010104/how-to-avoid-mouse-move-on-touch

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.  If you don't have anything useful to say then why bother answering?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe some help here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/turn-off-mouse-cursor-while-using-touch-screen/73221598-4dbb-4a96-835e-dc454800fb03

> **Method 1**: 
>   **Step 1**:
>   You may try using an external USB mouse and check
>   for the issue. 
>   
>   **Step 2**: 
>   You may have to enable “Display pointer trail”
>   option and disable “Hide Mouse pointer when typing” check if this
>   fixes the issue. Follow these steps: 
>   **a.** Press “Windows key + W” from
>   the keyboard. 
>   **b.** Type “Mouse” without quotes in the search box. 
>   **c.** Select “Mouse” option from the left panel. d. Select “Pointer Options”
>   tab. 
>   **e.** Place a check mark next to “Display pointer trail”. 
>   **f**. Then remove check mark next to “Hide Mouse pointer when typing” option.
>   **g.** Then click “Apply” and “Ok” to save the changes. h. Then check how it
>   works. 
>   
>   **Method 2**:
>   You may also try using the different combination of
>   the Function keys and check. This may vary depending on the make of
>   the computer.